# Which design pattern should be used for algorithm implemented with two libraries

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, design-patterns

My algorithm is implemented in two versions which each uses a specific library (MKL and ITK). These implementations are provided since one of the libraries only are available to our users. Note that at the compilation time only one should be loaded and get compiled. I was confused which design pattern should be used here.

Thanks

Comment: sounds like strategy pattern, although the compile time bit is more plugin...

Comment: So, you want to create two versions of your library, or just one which would work with whatever underlying library is available at runtime? I'd rather do the second one if I were you.

Comment: I prefer the second one as well, but still is there any pattern for that?

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the template way do a "strategy design pattern" in called a [policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design). It's described quite well in the first chapter of Andrei Alexandrescu's book "Modern C++ Design".  Why, the template way, you might ask? Because it's compile time and only the code you use will be compiled.

I can't explain much because I don't actually have much experience using this, but in brief, a template don't have to be a type (like int, Person, float, etc.), it can be a function or a class. So you can code something like
`Printer<ScreenStrategy> p; // or wathever!`